# Can't install lxml module

Tags: python, pip, lxml

I know this question has been asked before but I've tried pretty much every solution listed on every question I can find, all to no avail.

`Pip install lxml` doesn't work, nor does `easy_install lxml`. I have downloaded and tried a handful of different versions of lxml:

lxml-3.6.4-cp27-cp27m-win32 (WHL file)

lxml-3.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win32 (WHL file)

lxml-lxml-lxml-3.7.0-0-g826ca60.tar (GZ file)

I have also downloaded, and extracted everything from, both `libxml2` and `libxslt`. Now they are both sitting in their own unzipped folders.

When I run the installations from the command line, it appears to be working for a few seconds but eventually just fails. It either `fails with exit status 2` or `failed building wheel for lxml` or `could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxm12 installed?`.....I think it's installed but I have no clue what an installed libxm12 should look like. I unzipped and extracted everything from the libxm12 download.

I've also tried all the following commands from other SO posts, and each has failed:

`sudo apt-get install python-lxml`

`apt-get install python-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev`

`pip install --upgrade lxml`

`pip3 install lxml`

I have also looked up and attempted installing "prebuilt binaries" but those also don't seem to work.......

I don't want this post to just be me complaining that it wouldn't work so my question is: what is the simplest most straightforward way to put lxml onto my computer so I can use it in Python?

Comment: So are you on windows or on ubuntu linux? You first mention the Windows wheels for lxml, but then say you attempted to use `apt-get` for installation?

Comment: Also which Python version are you using? You mention wheels for different Python versions (2.7 and 3.6)

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention I'm on Windows and Python 3.5

Comment: In that case you downloaded the wrong wheels: You should try either *lxml‑3.7.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl* (if you are using 32bit Python) or *lxml‑3.7.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl* (if you are using 64bit Python)

Comment: I don't really know why but it failed again. Failed to build the wheel and failed to find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. I downloaded _lxml-3.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win32_

Comment: That is not the one I told you to try! The number after *cp* has to match your Python version, so for Python 3.5 you need one with cp**35**! Please try again with the correct ones (the exact file names I wrote in my previous comment)

Comment: I succeeded. Thanks so much for being patient and helping me, I know I'm a noob

Answer (score 1):

Install missing dependency `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`